# Random row selection with different probabilities

Tags: sql, select, random, mysqli, probability

I'm searching for a way to get from a table with 400-500 rows 1 random row but not with all the same probability.

For example:
My table looks like:

Object - Rank

- Object_A  Top
- Object_B  Low
- Object_C  Normal

I got 3 possible ranks for an object and I would like that an object with the rank "Top" got three times more chance to get taken. It should be like there are 3 rows with Object_A in the table. Same for Normal but only two times the chance.

For now I got this code...

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM objects ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say your rank column has these three values:

```
3 top
2 normal
1 low
```

Then what you can do is:

```
$rand = rand()%3 +1;

$result = mysqli_query($link, "
   SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM objects ORDER BY RAND() 
   ) as t 
   WHERE rank >= {$rand} LIMIT 1"
);
```

The key is to understand the where condition: `rank >= {$rand}`.

- When rand will be `== 3`, 33% chances, only 1 top record will be returned.
- When rand will be `== 2`, 33% chances, only 1 top record (50% chances) or 1 normal record (50% chances) will be returned, and so on.

You can adjust the weight by assigning a different number.
For example if you want the top row returned about ~80% of the times you can assign top the value of 10 and then do:

```
$rand = rand()%10 +1;
```